# Who can escape the Nonary Game?

Tags: code-golf, game

The Nonary Game is a fictional game played in the video game trilogy of the same name. Your goal is to find how many players (at best) can escape a given game, in as few bytes of code as possible.

### Rules of the game

- There are 9 players, numbered 1 to 9.
- All players start in the same room.
- There are any number of doors, each one with a 1 to 9 number. There may be duplicate or missing door numbers.
- Door are **one-way** connections between rooms. Each door can **only be used once**.
- Only groups of **3 to 5 players** can go through a door.
- A group can only go through a door if the **sum of their numbers modulo 9** matches the door’s number modulo 9.
- Any player who goes through a 9 door escapes (wins).

### Examples

```
┌───┬───┬───┐
│   6   4   9
│ < │   |   |
│   3   5   9
└───┴───┴───┘
```

`<` represents the starting point. All players start there.

In this setting, everybody can escape. There are various ways to achieve this, one of which is:

- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] go though door 6 ((1+2+3+4+5) % 9 = 6), while [6, 7, 8, 9] go through door 3 ((6+7+8+9) % 9 = 3). Everybody meets up in the second room.
- [1, 2, 3, 7] go through door 4, while [4, 5, 6, 8, 9] go through door 5.
- [1, 2, 3, 4, 8] go through one of the 9 doors, [5, 6, 7, 9] go through the other one.

```
┌───┬───┐
│   │   |
│ < 8   9
│   │   |
└───┴───┘
```

This time, at most 4 people can escape:

- [1, 3, 5, 8, 9] go through door 8.
- [1, 3, 5, 9] go through door 9.

Other lists of survivors are possible, such as [2, 3, 4] or [1, 4, 6, 7], but there's no way for more than 4 people to escape.

### The challenge

Given a map, output the maximum numbers of player who can escape.

- Don’t worry, you don’t need to parse my awful diagrams! Input is a labeled directed graph, which you can represent in any convenient format (edge set, adjacency matrix...).
- If your representation requires labels for rooms, you can use any consistent set of values. However, doors must be represented by the integers 1 to 9.
- The input will always have at least one 9 door. All 9 doors always lead to the exit, while other doors never do.
- Your submission can be a function or full program.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are banned.

### Test cases

Inputs are shown as lists of [door number, from room, to room] triplets, with 0 being the starting room and -1 being the exit. If you choose to use another format, you’ll have to convert them appropriately.

```
Input                                                                      Output
[[6, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1], [4, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2], [9, 2, -1], [9, 2, -1]]       9
[[8, 0, 1], [9, 1, -1]]                                                    4
[[9, 0, -1]]                                                               5
[[2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2], [9, 2, -1]]                                         0
[[2, 0, 1], [3, 1, 2], [9, 2, -1]]                                         3
[[1, 0, 1], [9, 1, -1], [1, 0, 2], [9, 2, -1]]                             4
[[2, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1], [5, 1, 2], [4, 0, 2], [9, 2, -1], [9, 2, -1]]       8
[[3, 0, 1], [4, 0, 1], [5, 0, 1], [9, 1, -1], [7, 1, 2], [9, 2, -1]]       7
[[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [4, 0, 1], [9, 1, -1], [8, 1, 2], [9, 2, -1]]       6
[[6, 0, 1], [7, 0, 1], [9, 1, -1], [9, 1, -1]]                             7
```

Comment: I know it's a relic of the game being 999, but it bugs me that you need to mod the door number by 9 because they don't want to escape through Door 0.

Comment: It might be worth making clearer in the description and pictorial examples that some doors bypass rooms. Also can doors ever go backwards? I.e. some people might go 0->1->exit and others go 0->2->1->exit?

Comment: @NickKennedy not sure what you mean by “bypass”. Doors can connect any room to any other room. It’s a directed graph.

Comment: If you think this series of rules could be made more interesting with the threat of spontaneous explosion as soon as anyone makes a mistake, please give the game a try. It's great.

Comment: @Grimy sure, but the pictorial examples and the first 5 actual examples have all of the doors leading from one room to the next one to the right.

Comment: @Abigail Yes, it can. Note that this shouldn't be difficult to handle: thanks to the "each door can only be used once" rule, you really shouldn't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 219 bytes

A slower but significantly shorter version using bitmasks instead of strings.

```javascript
f=(D,P=[511],e=m=0)=>P.map((X,r)=>[...Array(-~X)].map((_,p)=>D.map(([d,s,t],j)=>(N=(g=(n,k)=>n&&n%2+g(n>>1,++k,x+=n%2*k))(p&=X,x=0))<3|N>5|r-s|x%9^d%9||f(D.filter(_=>j--),A=[...P],e+!~t*N,A[r]^=p,A[t]^=p))),m=m>e?m:e)|m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZFba8JAEIXf@yu2D8qsmcRcmtqUTorgs/goLFGCJuIlFzahWAj@9XQ1gtDYVum@HGYGvnNmdhN@hMVCrvNST7NlVNcxwQgnJFzLCjCihExO/sRIwhxgilIVwjCMoZThJ@iHKQ@a0RxzNRo1hVhigWWAG9WCMcGKIMWtKtJuN@3Y2gpS37dQ07a410h1elvOIe/SFPfKj7851dh3K6kX1b7jzZYdr6piGBnxeldGEubkb3Sd45COUSYqpvZ4KHtjHAoZzChXWh6Vc44JJX70nrxGvErqRZYW2S4ydtkKYhDiBZmJTO3JhKcUmW4FAbvncc76ffb08J3snch341pkt0W2L5mtU2b7HN@@1a8hm7@Rnf@QnRbZunLnJr95o8tPd36@kAfXTf762IY8qL8A)

NB: The reason why it's slower is that we do not compute the powersets of the players. Given a bitmask of players \$X\$, we iterate on all \$(X \operatorname{AND} p)\$ for \$0\le p\le X\$ without deduplicating.

---

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>293 272</s>  271 bytes

Takes input in the format described in the challenge. This is a brute force search.

```javascript
f=(D,P=[17**6+'8'],e=m=0)=>P.map((X,r)=>X&&[...X].reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>y+x)],['']).map(p=>D.map(([d,s,t],j)=>p<99|p[5]|r-s|eval([...p].join`+`)%9^d%9||f(D.filter(_=>j--),A=[...P],e+!~t*p.length,A[r]=X.replace(eval(`/[${p}]/g`),''),A[t]=[A[t]]+p))),m=m>e?m:e)|m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdLdboIwFAfw@z0FS6a0cqjiF7KsLCY@gJcmTTeJFqcBaZAZzdhe3fHhog50mnFR4KT9nT8nLJy1s5qEcxnpy2AqdjuXogEMKTPMWq2rqT2Vg6A@bWBqD4nvSIRGECYvo2qVEUJGnIRi@j4RCDmwSepp0YF0yXZvqb3VNpgDU1WOs5Kk9iCX2BRWEHFYJOfkk2XFknV4HOqrWKwdD6WU5GQRzJdjbYwr1su0YsWxiwbEnXuRCNErtRe6jqFP073DJKp2/xXVJPHEcha9QZ@FnI6ShNJzkoiZOq6zhw/5yeuzMQZVTQ6ziFOWrlyTGGPwqW@LZ/9R4NjfTYLlKvAE8YIZchFjPVAaoBgcFGYld1B0g3PllgtjpV5X2ne/ZSuTb@YKcqcgNw@ZjSxzcx@/eW2/XG5cklv/kVsF2SiZc56/cWWXc3M@zfzz2DnEb5f0OOmXy72CfMS1T@SyLzHL5pXL5qVpNEubHMu983K3IHcPhlnO/fWb7zPvvgE) (the first test case times out on TIO)

#### How?

The array `P[]` holds a list of strings describing the players in each room.

We start with `P=['241375698']` (using \$17^6=24137569\$), which means that all players are initially located in room \$0\$.

For each room `X` at position `r`, we compute the powerset of `X`:

```javascript
[...X].reduce((a, x) => [...a, ...a.map(y => y + x)], [''])
```

For each group of players `p` in there and for each door `[d,s,t]` at index `j`, we test if the group is unable to pass through the door:

```javascript
                         // we can't pass if:
p < 99 |                 // there are less than 3 players
p[5] |                   // or there are more than 5 players
r - s |                  // or the source room s is not equal to the current room
eval([...p].join`+`) % 9 // or the sum of the players modulo 9
^ d % 9                  // does not match the ID of the door modulo 9
```

If the group can pass, we do a recursive call:

```javascript
f(                       //
  D.filter(_ => j--),    // remove the door that has just been used from D[]
  A = [...P],            // use a copy A[] of P[]
  e + !~t * p.length,    // if t = -1, add the length of p to e (number of escaped guys)
  A[r] = X.replace(      // remove the players from the source room A[r]
    eval(`/[${p}]/g`),   //
    ''                   //
  ),                     //
  A[t] = [A[t]] + p      // and append them to the target room A[t]
)                        //
```

We keep track of the maximum number of escaped players in `m` and eventually return it.

Comment: Are you just trying all possibilities?

Comment: @Jonah Yes. It may be either very fast or very slow depending on the constraints implied by the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 76 bytes

```
2ịịœc3r5¤ẎS,%9EʋƇ1ị${ḟ@;ƭⱮ€Ḋị¥ż€Ḋ{ṛṪ}¦ƒ€
ç@€Ẏ;ḷṢ€€Q
“”WẋḊ€FṀƊ9RW¤;Wçƒ@⁸ẈṪ$€Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4e5uIDo6Odm4yPTQkoe7@oJ1VC1dT3UfazcEiqtUP9wx38H62NpHG9c9alrzcEcXUPDQ0qN7IJzqhztnP9y5qvbQsmOTgCJch5c7gCR29Vk/3LH94c5FQA4QBXI9apjzqGFu@MNd3UBNQBG3hzsbjnVZBoUfWmIdfnj5sUkOjxp3PNzVATRLBWTAzob/Ryc93DnDGqhRQddOAajZ@nA71@F2oGTk///RXNHRZjoKhjoKRrE6CtHGCKYJkNZRMAYxTRFMSyCto2CAzIzVAZphgdBoCVYNFbcEi0M5RghFhphGoisxxqHEENMqiIGGhA2EMZF8ZIKpEd0M1FBBMgOLO8wJu9oIq3FIZljgMAMposyxaoQHPVcsAA)

A full program taking a single argument, a directed graph using rooms 1, 2, ... and 0 as exit. Returns an integer which is the maximum number that can escape. Full explanation to follow.

Should run without the `Ṣ€€Q` for a 4-byte saving but slow to rest.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 402 bytes

Little long, but very fast:

```py
from itertools import*
R=range
O=sorted
def f(r):
 q=[({0:{*R(1,10)}},r,0)]
 l,S=[],[]
 for D,r,C in q:
  l+=[len(D.get(-1,[]))]
  for i in D:
   for t in R(3,6):
    for j in combinations(D[i],t):
     for a,b in enumerate(r):
      if b[0]%9==sum(j)%9 and b[1]==i:
       if(str(U:={**D,i:O({*D[i]}-{*j}),b[2]:O({*D.get(b[2],[]),*j})}))not in S:q+=[(U,r[:a]+r[a+1:],C)];S+=[str(U)]
 return max(l+[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLNbqswEIX3PIU3lWwyqXDSn0DlVdlXStSV5QW5Mb2OwCTGke4V4tlT22kFVaiqsvHM4ZszM4bDf/u30cvVwZzPpWlqpKw0tmmqFqn60BgbR2tmCv0moxfWulzuop0sUYkNySJ0ZBx3SdbFa0yBJqTvwUBCRIQq2DAugLuwbAzKnf6MlEZHV4WqGeOV1Di/fZMWz6nDiC8KqPJY7rGQWp@u8RIeSNCCuPfin6beKl1Y1egW51wJsB9IYArYekrqUy1NYeVl4vCoEm15Im5SxtpTjffkJkWF3jmRCsbUJ@Y43FqDXzPWxXEOKnvBXew79fMu3vcEtnwhLmLYxKd@F/Ave0J0E6bfZEe3MH4Fw7NCzAwvZjQT8EzE08a9CC38@kbak9GoLv7haubmI@eDUdriEnP@ACgBRAUgvhzCO3cCWvjwfghTdwKa0y@xu@FosFsNHmkovCLSQFzJi6GQTnT8Fl7@CNOJkS5dkt90@QxH93E3YfG93dfrHdlNTff4m7UWk85ju9WPdqP/4HHaY/w9z@8)